# sleep() is not delaying printf() output correctly

Tags: c, sleep

I am having problems with the `sleep()` function not working. For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

     printf("\nHello!");
     sleep(1);
     printf("\nBye!");
     sleep(1);

     return 0;
}
```

Even simple programs like this won't work. It will sleep for 2 seconds then say "Hello! Bye!" and end the program. If anyone has any ideas they are appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-string

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Output to stdout is buffered until a newline.
[The newline immediately preceding the printf should flush, but the following characters will be buffered until a newline or explicit flush is forced {re: greg h}]

To flush stdout, call `fflush( stdout )`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    printf("\nHello!");
    // flush stdout
    fflush( stdout );
    sleep(1);
    printf("\nBye!");
    // flush stdout
    fflush( stdout );
    sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you give an example? I am 14 and just learning the language sorry if im a little slow

Comment: The `printf` statements *do* contain newlines, just in an unusual place...

Comment: @Greg Hewgill printf does not contain newlines.. you have to put an escape character, but it doesn't flush automatically without it.

Comment: @James: No, really, there are newlines at the *start* of the output in the code in the question.

Comment: haha, touche... the newlines would force a flush, but the following characters would be buffered. I updated my answer to include an example, and I will change my wording somewhat

Answer (score 1):

By default, `printf` output is flushed (actually sent to the terminal) when a `\n` character is printed. So you can make your code work as follows:

```
 printf("Hello!\n");
 sleep(1);
 printf("Bye!\n");
 sleep(1);
```

In this case, I have moved the newline `\n` to the *end* of the string you are printing, instead of the beginning.